# Crear Clave Foranea de un integer y no un bigIncrements en Laravel Migrations

Tags: laravel

se me está presentando el siguiente problema:

Quiero crear por migrations de Laravel una clave foranea pero es hacia un valor que es integer no incremental.

Tengo 2 tablas. Users y Clients.

La relación entre ellas quiero que sea la cédula de identidad que se llama el campo rut.

En Users está el campo rut que es integer y en Clients tengo la clave foranea hacia rut pero no me funciona.

Código:

```
Users:

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('rut');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('rol_id');
        $table->foreign('rol_id')->references('rol_id')->on('rols');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('providence_id');
        $table->foreign('providence_id')->references('providence_id')->on('providences');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('commune_id');
        $table->foreign('commune_id')->references('commune_id')->on('communes');
        $table->string('names');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

Employees:

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('rut');
        $table->foreign('rut')->references('rut')->on('users');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('gender_id');
        $table->foreign('gender_id')->references('gender_id')->on('genders');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('nationality_id');
        $table->foreign('nationality_id')->references('nationality_id')->on('nationalities');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('civil_state_id');
        $table->foreign('civil_state_id')->references('civil_state_id')->on('civil_states');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('region_id');
        $table->foreign('region_id')->references('region_id')->on('regions');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('providence_id');
        $table->foreign('providence_id')->references('providence_id')->on('providences');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('commune_id');
        $table->foreign('commune_id')->references('commune_id')->on('communes');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('health_id');
        $table->foreign('health_id')->references('health_id')->on('healths');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('pention_id');
        $table->foreign('pention_id')->references('pention_id')->on('pentions');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('contract_type_id');
        $table->foreign('contract_type_id')->references('contract_type_id')->on('contract_types');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('branch_office_id');
        $table->foreign('branch_office_id')->references('branch_office_id')->on('branch_offices');
        $table->longText('father_lastname');
        $table->longText('mother_lastname');
        $table->longText('address');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('cellphone');
        $table->date('born_date');
        $table->date('entrance_health');
        $table->date('entrance_pention');
        $table->date('entrance_company');
        $table->date('exit_company');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

Me muestra el siguiente error:

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `jis`.`clients` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `clients` add constraint `clients_rut_foreign` foreign key (`rut`) references `users` (`rut`))
```

¿Qué podría ser el error?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

tienes error porque al crear el constraint no coinciden los tipos de datos, si tienes una pk en la tabla user que es de tipo int, la fk de la tabla Employees debe ser tambien int no bigint por eso te da problema, puedes usar int pues no creo que te haga falta memoria para almacenar un id pues tendrias que tener mas de 2147483647 usuarios